# Separable extension has finitely many intermediate subfields

Tags: galois-theory

If I have a separable finite extension $L/K$, is it true that there are finitely many intermediate subfields? I know this is true if it is also a normal extension by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory. I can also show this if I use the primitive element theorem however I'm trying to use this fact to then prove the primitive element theorem later.

What I want to do is try to make $L$ sit inside some normal extension of $K$ but is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: The answer is yes, by the primitive element theorem. In fact, a finite separable extension admits a primitive element, and this is equivalent to ask that there are finitely many subextensions. See for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem

Comment: Hi Ferra, thank you for your comment and reference, however as stated in my question I'm trying to do this without using the primitive element theorem!

Comment: sorry I didn't read that part...

Answer (score 2):

Extend $L$ to its Galois closure $M$ and let $G$ be its Galois group. Any intermediate extension between $K$ and $L$ is also an  intermediate extension between $K$ and $M$ and these are in bijection with the subgroups of $G$. $G$ is a finite group, so its subgroups are finite in number.

More precisely, let $L$ be the field of elements fixed by the subgroup $H$ of $G$. The subextensions of $L$ are the fields of invariants of the subgroups of $G$ which contain $H$.

Comment: I've never come across the Galois closure before, is there a way without using this idea?

Comment: I don't know away. But it's very simple: the  extension field of $K$ generated by all the conjugates of the elements of $L$. Once you know $L$ is a simple extension, it's the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of a primitive element.

Comment: Ah okay, who do we know that $L$ is simple?

Comment: The criterion for being a simple extension is precisely to have a finite number of intermediate extension fields. The definition of the Galois closure is that it is the smallest Galois extension contained in an algebraic closure of $L$.

Comment: We do not need that $L/K$ is simple to get an easy construction of the galois closure. $L/K$ is finite, hence finitely generated. Take the minimal polynomials of a finite set of generators. These are all separable. Now take the splitting field of those poynomials. This a galois extension which contains $L$.

Comment: @Bernard Is it true that given a finite separable extension $K:F$, the Galois closure of $K:F$ is finite? If so, can you give a hint as to how to show it.

Comment: @caffeinemachine: Yes, it's true. Roughly, the finite separable extension $L$ is generated by a finite number of separable elements. Take all roots of the minimal polynomials of these elements in an algebraic closure of $L$. These roots are finite in number, and they generate the Galois closure.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. I get it now.

Comment: why G is a finite group?